# Specify command in spec to uninstall RPM package

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I have built an RPM package and to install the package I run

```
rpm -Uvh --force rpm_package_name.rpm
```

Is there any command that I can define in spec during rpm build so that it uninstalls the package in single go, just like install works.

Answer (score 1):

NO.

you cannot force in advance how the user will use `rpm`, `zypper` or `yum` to install or uninstall your package.

The question I would ask: how come the user needs to use `--force` to uninstall your rpm? In that case I would suggest you to try building an rpm that does not need special flags to get uninstalled.

Comment: I am using ```--force``` to install the ```rpm``` (as user might be installing same package twice) and not to uninstall it. Actually when I install my rpm package it gets installed under /usr/lib/test/ , all I want it when user uses uninstall with my rpm package name then all the files and folders inside /usr/lib/test/gets deleted.

Comment: if you uninstall the `rpm`, then all files listed in the `%files` section of the spec file will be removed as well.

Comment: can you help me with the command to uninstall rpm package that has been build using ```rpmbuild```, as ```rpm -e rpm_package_name.rpm``` is not working

Comment: `rpm -e` should work. If it does not work you should ask a new question.